# Can I build a wooden staircase on a concrete slab and meet code?

Tags: deck, stairs, slab, footings

I'm currently in the process of replacing the front stairs on my house and my original plan was to go with a precast stone/granite staircase. To support this I poured this 6'x8'x6" pad to have the precast step placed on. The more I think about this the more I'm convinced that it doesn't make sense to spend the money on a precast step ($7000) vs the roughly $1200 it would cost to build a stair/landing out of PT and composite decking. An added bonus is that the latter would match the deck that was built on the back of the house last year.

Would it be possible to build on this slab and still meet code or would that require actual footings?

[image]

Comment: Who's code?  Codes vary by location.  Most likely there is a way for this to be done without requiring foundation work.

Answer (score 1):

A freestanding deck doesn't require frost footings in most cases. Anything attached to the house does. You decide.

Somewhat ironically, I'd have considered the precast step to require proper footings due to its weight, but not the deck. Modern practice is to install full supporting foundation under such heavy structures.